# Can a graceless exit corrupt the C++ memory allocator?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, embedded, dynamic-memory-allocation

It is well known that the usual cause of a `std::bad_malloc` being thrown is when memory is exhausted.

I'm executing an embedded, bare metal (without Operating System) application. The initial allocation sometimes succeeds, and sometimes fails. Since there is no other code running (no OS, no other processes), I have good reason to believe that this `std::bad_alloc` is more complex than allocating more memory than is available to the system. When it works, there is ~500kB of memory allocated. The hardware has been allocated 16MB.

Instead, it seems that the system has an incorrect record of how much memory is allocated, specifically that when the allocator begins, it thinks some non-zero amount of memory has already been allocated.

When a bare metal application starts, it should have identically zero memory allocated. It seems that is not the case here.

Is it possible that some state in the memory allocator is being retained between soft resets? How can I find out how the allocation is being done?

This is running on an ARMv7 with gcc (Sourcery CodeBench Lite 2013.05-40) 4.7.3, and linking against libstdc++6.0. We are compiling with `-O0 -g`.

We are allocating both `std::` objects and user-defined objects with the `new` keyword, and the standard allocator.

Comment: It is implementation specific. So edit your question to improve it by telling much more (which compiler & version, which `libstdc++` & version, how is `::operator new` implemented, how -with which optimizations- are you compiling, etc etc...).

Comment: Even the edit does not tell enough. How is actually the memory allocator done?

Comment: It all depends on whether you (and your libraries) initialize variables, or rely on power-up reset to give them expected values.  Soft reset doesn't restore everything to power-up defaults.

Comment: Right, so how do I find those things out? I'll edit the question...

Comment: libstdc++ uses the memory allocation services of the standard C library (malloc/free); so we need to know what C library is being used - the default glibc requires a POSIX environment, so on a bare-metal system you are most probably using an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

If state is retained between restarts, then this is most likely due to incorrect initialisation at start-up.

It is the responsibility of the C++ runtime start-up to initialise the standard library.  In a bare-metal system this includes initialising the heap and memory allocator.  How this is done, and whether you have to perform any special action will depend on your particular tool-chain and library.

In ARM RealView (also used by Keil MDK-ARM) for example, you normally specify the heap size explicitly in the start-up code configuration.  In other cases it is common for the linker script to automatically allocate all available memory that is not statically allocated or allocated to the stack to be allocated to the heap automatically.  The linker script still needs to know the location and size of available RAM of course.  Check your linker's map file output to verify the size and location of the heap.

Most embedded system libraries include stubs that must be user-implemented to match the library to the target - mostly this is related to I/O, but in the *Newlib* library (often used with GCC bare-metal toolchains) for example, the `sbrk` (or `sbrk_r`) stub must be reimplemented for correct heap operation.  The implementation of `sbrk` is critical to the correct operation of the heap.

---

**Added**

It appears that Sourcery CodeBench Lite uses Newlib.  I have seen implementations that start as follows:

```
caddr_t _sbrk(int incr) 
{

    extern char _ebss; // Defined by the linker
    static char *heap_end;
    char *prev_heap_end;

    if (heap_end == 0) { ...
```

This is potentially unsafe if the runtime initialisation does not correctly initialise static data to zero (some embedded systems do that for faster start-up; though it is seldom worth the potential for bugs).  Verify that your start-up performs zero-initialisation correctly and in any case explicitly initialise `heap_end` to zero:

```
static char *heap_end = 0 ;
```

in order to guarantee that it will work regardless of the strict correctness or otherwise of the start-up.

Comment: Very informative. Yes, my `_sbrk()` looks very similar. The `heap_end` is zero initialized. Where could I look for the zero-initialization? But, even if the heap had junk left in it, could it cause a `bad_alloc`?

Comment: @Cuadue :  I am hypothesising that rather the "having junk left in", it is simply a matter of not being initialised correctly which would have non-deterministic results.  You should perhaps be clearer on what you mean by a "soft reset" - is the C runtime initialisation *definitely* executed on such a reset?

Comment: We poke the CPU registers to stop the clock, issue a reset, and start the clock again. An attached JTAG debugger indicates that the program starts executing from the boot vector (address 0).

Comment: @Cuadue :  Perhaps not related to your problem, but I wonder why you explicitly stop the clock since all peripheral registers will be restored to their reset state on a true reset in any case?  "ARMv7" refers to a number of cores, Cortex-M (ARMv7-M/v7E-M) for example, reset is issued via the NVIC, although it is also possible to simply stop resetting a watchdog timer.  Neither is the same as simply jumping to the reset vector, which would not reset the stack-pointer to its reset state for example.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know why we have to stop the clock, but it's what the vendor recommends. Good point about the SP and LR, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 0):

A good implementation of memory allocation should not get corrupted by allocating all available memory (or trying to allocate more than all) , such that `std::bad_alloc` is called. It is of course possible that there are bugs in the memory allocator in the OS you are using - there is no telling. But a "good" allocator should not get corrupted or stop working simply because your application allocated until it got `std::bad_alloc`.

However, whether just exiting the application with `exit(1)` at that point will free up the memory allocated by the application code or not depends on your operating system. If it handles cleanup of exiting application code, then you're safe. If the OS doesn't, then you need to catch the exception and clean everything up yourself. Since there are literally many hundreds of operating systems in existance, it's impossible to answer the question in a general way.

It should be pretty easy to test this: Just write an application that allocates a lot of memory in a loop, run it several times times and determine if the number of iterations in the loop is about the same number or, for example, reduces for each run of the application - in the latter case, you have some sort of problem.

Comment: the initial question explicitely stated this is bare metal (no OS) embedded code. Discussing the duties of the OS is probably pointless in this regard.